# Adding a Link "Advanced Search" next to ootb search

Tags: 2007, master-page, top-link-bar

How do I add a link "Advanced Search" next to the OOTB search (top area where I see the title of the site, etc.)

[Print shot is here](http://img146.imageshack.us/i/advancedsearch.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised:

I am not sure of the process for editing the delegate control the implements the SearchBoxEx control.
Your control is provided by an xml document in the OSearchBasicFeature.
The file can be found in your [12or14hive]\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\OSearchBasicFeature\SearchArea.xml

[This article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sridhara/project-to-customize-the-small-search-control-in-sharepoint-2007) talks about overriding that.

To edit the standard search webpart:

1. Edit the *standard search* webpart
2. Go to "Miscellaneous" section
3. Toggle "Display advanced search
   link" on
4. Set the url for "Advanced Search
   page Url"
5. Click "Apply" or "Okay"

Comment: I already have that working. Now I need to put a link next to where to regular search is. I will be calling this "Advanced Search".

Comment: The advanced search page (advsearch.aspx) has 3 webparts and all for search. I have no idea what you are suggesting. I am missing something here.

Comment: Sorry, ammended

Comment: You just have to edit your "regular search" webpart.

Comment: Edit page only make content placeholder items (web parts) available. The left nav and top nav areas stay static.

Comment: It looks like I want to put the link in this area. (I meant below the OOTB search)

<td class="ms-sbscopes ms-sbcell"><select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderSearchArea$ctl01$SBScopesDDL" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderSearchArea_ctl01_SBScopesDDL" title="Search Scope" class="ms-sbscopes">
<option selected="selected" value="This Site">This Site: Customer Site</option>

Comment: In that case you need to edit the masterpage to add the link.